# Make a NDVI Chart for two different locations

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I made this code to make a chart of the mean NDVI of two different regions. But this code gives this error.
Error:
`"Error generating chart: Collection.first: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections"`.

```
var provinces = table.merge(table2);
print(provinces);

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
        .map(maskS2clouds)
        .filterDate('2023-02-15', '2023-03-15')
        .filterBounds(provinces);

var ndvi_func = function (image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var S2_ndvi = S2.map(ndvi_func);

var reduced = S2_ndvi.map(function(image){
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection:provinces , 
    reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 10
  });
})

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: reduced,
  regions: provinces,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
}).setSeriesNames(['Field 1', 'Field 2']).setOptions({
  title: 'Mean NDVI Time Series',
  hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Mean NDVI'}
});

print(chart);
```

Comment: Your `reduced` variable is obtained by mapping a function that takes an ee.Image as input, and returns a ee.FeatureCollection as output. So `reduced` is a FeatureCollection of FeatureCollections. You are then taking this object and passing it to ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion, which should take an ee.ImageCollection as input.  I suggest trying getting rid of `reduced`.. perhaps you want to pass `S2_ndvi` directly to ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion